# HTML/Java- Loading a new page for a calculated answer then having a go back button

Tags: javascript, browser-history, document.write

I am using: 
`document.write ("temperature is" + c.toString())` to get the calculation on the next page. I do understand that to put the history back button into the page I need to do this:

```html
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>
```

but I cannot figure out how to get that into the new page that `document.write` loads when my function is executed.
Should I not be using `document.write`? Or how do I put it into my function?

Here is my entire function:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ToC() {
        var f = parseFloat(strIn);
        var c = (f - 32) * 5/9;
        document.tempform.temp.value = c.toString();   
    }
    document.write("Temperature is " + c.toString());
    }
</script>
```

Comment: From where **strIn** is coming?

Answer (score 0):

Write the button with `document.write`, but then add the click event afterwards.

```
  document.write("<button id='back'>Go Back</button>");
  document.getElementById('back').onclick=function(){
    window.history.back();
  };
```

Here's a demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lxx781dm/

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting value for **strIn** variable then the only change required is below :

```
<script>
function ToC() 
{
    var f = parseFloat(strIn);
    var c = (f - 32) * 5/9;;
    document.tempform.temp.value = c.toString();    
    document.write("Temperature is " + c.toString())
}
</script>
```

Also you have to take care of below line as well :

```
    document.tempform.temp.value = c.toString();
```

This line states that you want to save the value in a form having name **tempform** and an field having name **temp**, so you should have something like below in you page :

```
<form name="tempform">
<input type="text" name="temp" />
</form>
```